# Update same record in different tables

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables:

table 1 = userfiles
table 2 = uploaded

Both tables have multiple columns but have one same column: Title ('ID's are different)

if i update the value of one userfiles.Title it should also update the value of the same uploaded.Title.

```
if(isset($_POST["btnSubmit"])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $titlefield = $_REQUEST['titlefield'];

    $Title = 'Title';


    $errors = array();


    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","12345","phpfiles");  

    $query = "UPDATE userfiles, uploaded
                SET userfiles.$Title='$titlefield',
                    uploaded.$Title='$titlefield'
                WHERE
                    userfiles.ID = '$id'
                    uploaded.title='$titlefield'";

    $update2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    mysqli_close($conn);

    $count = count($errors);

    if($count != 0){
        foreach($errors as $error){
            echo $error."<br/>";
        }
    }       
}
```

if i update (through php web form) userfiles.title(aaaaa) to 'ddddd' it should also update uploaded.title(aaaaa) to (ddddd)

but nothing gets updated

Comment: Updating 2 tables with one UPDATE statement is possible but you have to join the tables. It might be easiest for you just to do two separate updates since you don't have a column with which to join.

Comment: is it then not better to update Uploaded with the value from Userfiles?how do you do that ?

Comment: Do you really need to have the column in both tables? If they always have to be the same, you should just put it in one place and use a join to get the value when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Run first update

```
$query = "UPDATE userfiles
            SET userfiles.$Title='$titlefield'
            WHERE
                userfiles.ID = '$id'";
$update2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Run second update

```
$query = "UPDATE uploaded
            SET uploaded.$Title='$titlefield'
            WHERE
                uploaded.title='$titlefield'";
$update2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```